# Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5, linking ndk app fails to locate module .so and .a

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I have an ndk project with two modules:

- abwrenderer - native library module
- app - native and java hybrid, glues java to the abwrenderer

I just updated to AS 2.0 Preview 5 this morning, and encountered some gradle related issues.

I upgraded to gradle-2.10 and switched to gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5.  When attempting to debug, an ndk build is triggered and I run into the following problem:

Error:error: C:\android\projects\foo\abwrenderer\build\intermediates\binaries\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libabwrenderer.so: No such file or directory

Now when I was on gradle-2.9 & gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha3, the libraries were built in this directory.  After this morning's upgrades, the libraries are now located in:
C:\android\projects\foo\abwrenderer\build\libs\abwrenderer\shared\armeabi-v7a\debug

Is there a way to update the search location for project dependencies that build libraries?

For reference, I define the dependency on abwrenderer project as follows (build.gradle (app)):

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
           source {
                srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
            }
            dependencies {
                project ":abwrenderer" buildType "debug" linkage "shared"
            }
        }
        jniLibs {
            source {
                srcDirs 'src/main/libs'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And build.gradle for abwrenderer project is as follows:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.native"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "abwrenderer"
        cppFlags.addAll(["--std=c++11",
                      "-fexceptions",
                      "-frtti"])
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv3", "log", "dl"])
        stl = "c++_static"
        debuggable = true
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
           jni {
                exportedHeaders {
                  srcDir "src/main/jni"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I have invalidated caches and restarted, done a clean build, etc.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See the question I just asked, the syntax for repositories at the top may be what you're looking for to include static/shared libs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959013/ndk-debugging-with-gradle-experimental-plugin

Comment: Have you tried with `gradle-experimental:0.7.0'`?

Answer (score 0):

Your **defaultConfig** and **ndk** blocks were missing some info.  They should look similar to this:

`defaultConfig {
            applicationId = 'com.myapp.abwrenderer'
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 13
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = '1.0'
        }
ndk     {
            platformVersion = 21
            moduleName = 'abwrenderer'
            toolchain = 'clang'
            stl = 'gnustl_static'
            cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11'])
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'EGL', 'GLESv3', 'log', 'dl'])
        }`

You should take a look at the following NDK sample from Google to see how they did it: [hello-libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs)